# How to split a string by | using python where | is not present inside () using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, split

Hi I am new to python.

I am trying to split a string by | where | is not present inside () using regular expression. But so far no luck. Any pointers?

Example:

```
OUTPUT" "PROCEDURE" [ "IS" ] procedure-name [ ( "THROUGH" | "THRU" ) procedure-name ] | "GIVING" { file-name }+
```

The above string should get splatted into two strings:

String1: `OUTPUT" "PROCEDURE" [ "IS" ] procedure-name [ ( "THROUGH" | "THRU" ) procedure-name ]`

String2:  `"GIVING" { file-name }+`

Comment: Did you consider using `str.split('|')` ?

Comment: Yes I did. But I want to ignore | if it is present inside (). Hence str.split('|') won't give the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.split()` function with specific regex pattern:

```
import re

s = 'OUTPUT" "PROCEDURE" [ "IS" ] procedure-name [ ( "THROUGH" | "THRU" ) procedure-name ] | "GIVING" { file-name }+'
result = re.split(r'\|(?![^(]*\))', s)

print(result)  # the list, containing 2 strings
```

The output:

```
['OUTPUT" "PROCEDURE" [ "IS" ] procedure-name [ ( "THROUGH" | "THRU" ) procedure-name ] ', ' "GIVING" { file-name }+']
```

---

`(?![^(]*\))` - lookahead negative assertion ensures that there's no closing brace `)` after delimiter `|`

`[^(]` - matches any character except opening brace `(`

`\)` - matches closing brace `)`

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly fine. Will it be possible for you to explain what each symbol in this (?![^(]*\)) signifies? This will help me to build a expression of my own next time.

Answer (score 0):

A beautiful example for the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` mechanism which is supported by the newer [**`regex` module**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex):

```
import regex as re

rx = re.compile(r'\([^)]*\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\|')
string = """OUTPUT" "PROCEDURE" [ "IS" ] procedure-name [ ( "THROUGH" | "THRU" ) procedure-name ] | "GIVING" { file-name }+"""

parts = rx.split(string)
print(parts)
# ['OUTPUT" "PROCEDURE" [ "IS" ] procedure-name [ ( "THROUGH" | "THRU" ) procedure-name ] ', ' "GIVING" { file-name }+']
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/8jzJQN/1).

Answer (score 0):

Lookahead positive ]:

```
re.split(r'(?<=] )\|',string)
Out[44]: 
['OUTPUT" "PROCEDURE" [ "IS" ] procedure-name [ ( "THROUGH" | "THRU" ) procedure-name ] ',
 ' "GIVING" { file-name }+']
```